How to Exclude everything after a character/string from an output in Linux
This is my file:
abc.test.com
efg.test.com:80/test1/123/xyz
xyz.test.com:443/test1
xab.test.com:80
lmn.test.com/100
com.test.com:10

I am trying to remove all characters after the string ".com", but I want to include ".com" in it.
I tried sed 's/.com.*//', however it seems to exclude ".com" as well:
$ cat test1.txt | grep .com | sed 's/.com.*//'
abc.test
efg.test
xyz.test
xab.test
lmn.test
com.test

Is there a way to remove all characters after a particular string, however the output should still have that string it.

Replace it with .com, not an empty string.

Why shouldn't it remove .com as well. Isn't that exactly what you told it to do?

If sed supported lookbehinds you could use that, but it doesn't.

BTW, you should escape the first .. Otherwise it will also match Xcom for any X.

Escape the first '.' (e.g. \.) or use a character-class [.]

What should the output be if the input was xab.com.com:80 or xab.com.test.com:80 or xab.com.co.uk:80?

Or www.comicrelief.co.uk or www.commercialcars.com

You don't have to use both grep and sed, you can just use either one of them.
Your code 's/.com.*// replaces the match with an empty string instead of the .com that you want to keep, and also note that you have to escape the dot \. or also it would match any character.

If you are using grep, and there is just a single occurrence of .com on the line, you can match that part and then output the match with -o
grep -o ".*\.com" file

An alternative using awk replacing the match with .com
awk '{sub(/\.com.*/, ".com")}1' file

Both will output
abc.test.com
efg.test.com
xyz.test.com
xab.test.com
lmn.test.com
com.test.com

Note that the difference is that the sed and awk solutions will print a line that does not contain .com as they are doing a substition and then print that whole line.
The grep solution will not display a line without .com as it prints the output for a match.

A quick trick is to "replace" the matching part with the string you want there:
sed 's/\.com.*/.com/`


Perhaps sed  's/\(\.com\).*/\1/' file as then the regexp to keep the part may be more expressive. e.g. \(\.\(com\|org\|uk\|etc\)\)\>.*.

@potong You're right; though that would require to explain the capture groups, etc... and the \| (OR oprator) isn't part of the sed standard

I think you will find the OR operator goes under the name of alternation see section 9.4.7 of the posix manual.

standard sed is BRE; alternation is ERE. For once I don't agree with GNU's choice of adding the alternation to sed in BRE mode, as it is misleading. They could have kept it for the -E switch, like in other UNIXes

This might help the bewildered by the different flavors of regular expressions BRE, ERE and PCRE.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt
abc.test.com
efg.test.com:80/test1/123/xyz
xyz.test.com:443/test1
linetoignore
xab.test.com:80
lmn.test.com/100
com.test.com:10

then
awk '{start=index($0,".com")}start{print substr($0,1,start+3)}' file.txt

gives output
abc.test.com
efg.test.com
xyz.test.com
xab.test.com
lmn.test.com
com.test.com

Explanation: I use String Functions first index to determine where .com is. If there is not .com 0 is returned. Note that index is looking for substring NOT matching pattern, so there is no need to escape ., which would be required e.g. in match function. If start is non-zero I print substring of whole line starting at 1st character and ending at start plus 3 position, as .com has 4 characters.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

The comments note that your approach might fail in presence of lines like:
www.comicrelief.co.uk

To avoid this, you would need a way to decide if .com is the last part of the domain.
For example, if / and : cannot appear, then they demarcate the end of the domain, and you could use a command like:
awk -F'[/:]' '{print $1}'

or
sed 's|[/:].*||'

Or, if your grep supports -o:
grep -o '^[^/:]*'

